# TYPO3 8.7.32: Adding a Icon to Social Links

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have created a link to an external page in TYPO3 with the type "Social Links" which all works. But I do not know where and how to add an icon here.
Does anyone know how I can change this?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
It turns out that this is the bootstrap_packages extension. However, it is not possible to add an icon in this extension.

Comment: I've never seen this page type before. Is this maybe a custom extension?

Comment: According to the screenshot, it's not a page type but a content element. Nevertheless, it's nothing that ships with TYPO3 by default. Thus you need to check the list of installed extensions and tell us which extension it is (e.g. the extension key). If it's a public extension from TER, we might help you. If it's a custom  made extension it's rather hard without access to the TYPO3 installation.

Comment: Hello @PeterKraume , I checked my list of installed extensions and found that it is the bootstrap_package. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So your problem is solved? It might help others when you post a detailed explanation how you added the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is the bootstrap_packages extension. However, it is not possible to add an icon in this extension.

Alternatively, I used HTML to create an image with a link.

```html
<a href="foo" target="_blank"><img class="facebook_icon" src="FB_Icon_white.svg" height="25px" alt="facebook_icon" /></a>
```